# Create a Joystick/D-Pad in Xcode to move UIImageView (containing character)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, joystick

I have a UIImageView connected to a game I coded. However I would like to know how I could move this UIImageView via a Joystick/D-Pad. I have not coded a JoyStick or a D-Pad as I don't know how to. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how I could go abouts doing this.

---

**Edit:**

A virtual joystick (in the app).

Comment: you mean a virtual one or a real one?

Comment: imageView.center = CGPointMake(x,y);

Comment: virtual one. not a real one. Im gonna update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking to create a virtual dpad try the following:

Create 4 UIButton objects, and set them up with direction arrow graphics (I would recommend doing this part in IB).

Then Create 4 seperate IBAction methods and link them to your buttons through IB or programmatically in `viewDidLoad`.

Each IBAction method should look something like this:

```
-(IBAction)moveLeft:(id)sender{
     myImageView.center = CGPointMake(myImageView.center.x-10, myImageView.center.y); 
}

-(IBAction)moveRight:(id)sender{
     myImageView.center = CGPointMake(myImageView.center.x+10, myImageView.center.y); 
}

-(IBAction)moveUp:(id)sender{
     myImageView.center = CGPointMake(myImageView.center.x, myImageView.center.y-10); 
}

-(IBAction)moveDown:(id)sender{
     myImageView.center = CGPointMake(myImageView.center.x, myImageView.center.y+10); 
}
```

You can change 10 to any number of pixels you want your image to move.

If you want the view to be animated when you move it you can wrap your movement code insdide an animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
     myImageView.center = CGPointMake(myImageView.center.x, myImageView.center.y+10); 
}];
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with a jailbroken iphone, you can try out [this tutorial](http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial) for using rs232 for serial communication with the iphone/ipod.

Otherwise if you want to do things legitimately, an exernal joystick connected to the iphone's 30 pin seral connection, or through bluetooth requires that you are a [Registered iOS Developer](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/)(RAD), and also part of the [Made for iPod Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)(MFI).

Setting up communication with an accessory on iOS requires the use of the  [ExternalAccessoryFramework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html), of which there is an Apple example project here: [EADemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079), and an Apple walkthrough here [External Accessory Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502).

There is also an Apress book called  [Building iPhone OS Accessories](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430229315), and a related demo project of a pong game which is similar to what you want to do. The book walks you through how to set up the EAAccessoryFramwork code, as well as how to build the game controller hardware, but does not describe how to write any firmware for the accessory, as you need to be an MFi licence to attain this information.

I hope that is enough to get you started. :)

Comment: Wow very useful information in here, but I think he meant a virtual joystick/keypad as he said "coded".  Thanks for the information however!

Comment: Oh I see, but yeah no problem, I had to find out all this stuff the hard way, so I thought I would share it as it may save some one some time. :)

Comment: I've been thinking about fiddling with hardware connecting to the iPhone for a while, so you helped me understand the steps needed to begin (and crushed my motivation because of all the hoops I would have to jump through, but that's not your fault haha)

Comment: +1, but I *almost* didn't - the jailbreaking link isn't really appropriate here IMHO. That's a minor issue though, and the rest is insanely useful.

Comment: Haha, yeah I work for a product dev company, and we are working on our first accessory for the iphone. We were all shocked when we found out how much red tape you need to cut through before you can start with the basics. Thats apple for you.

Comment: hey, this is really interesting, but I did mean a virtual joystick (in my app)!!